# Не равномерно запускается таймер

Tags: jquery

Почему между первым и вторым `div` есть некий пробел, а между остальным уже все стабильно? Или это зависит от браузера?
На названия функций, переменных и т.д. не обращайте внимание. Делаю черновик.

```js
var all = 8;
var num = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(str, 500);
});


function str() {
    if (num > all) {
        return 0;
    }
    num++;
    $('#s' + num).addClass('slideshow_img');
    setTimeout(str, 500);
}
```

```css
.slideshow_block {
    width: 630px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshow_img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(650px, 0);
    animation-name: slideshow_anim;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}

@keyframes slideshow_anim {
    from {
        transform: translate(700px, 0);
    } to {
        transform: translate(-100px, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow_block">
    <div id="s1" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s2" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s3" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s4" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s5" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s6" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s7" class="" ></div>
    <div id="s8" class="" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: То, что вы пытаетесь сделать, уже есть в CSS и называется `animation-delay`, а дело не в таймере, а в позиционировании. Всё встает на место, если везде прописать 630px вместо 650 и 700

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.